# Quando usare "maiuscola" e quando "maiuscolo"?

Tags: word-usage

Ho sempre avuto dei dubbi su quando si debba usare il termine "maiuscola" e  quando invece si adoperi "maiuscolo". Infatti, nel commento a una correzione che ho fatto recentemente ho scritto "maiuscole", ma non ero sicura se dovessi invece usare "maiuscoli". Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Answer (score 3):

È corretto dire

> Dopo un punto fermo si pone uno spazio seguito dal maiuscolo.
>
> L'uso del maiuscolo denota l'inizio di un nuovo periodo.

questo perché *maiuscolo* si riferisce più generalmente all'*azione* di capitalizzare una lettera.

*Maiuscola*, invece, è specifico

> Dopo un punto fermo la lettera successiva è maiuscola.

Infatti, nella maggior parte dei casi, *maiuscola* sarà implicitamente riferito alla lettera in questione.

> In inglese però l'uso della (*lettera*) maiuscola è più largo che in italiano.

Aggiungerei che è molto spesso possibile usare i due termini intercambiabilmente, con i dovuti apporti; ad esempio, la terza frase potrebbe essere riformulata nel seguente modo.

> Dopo un punto fermo la lettera successiva è *in maiuscolo*.

Comment: «"maiuscoli" non è una parola italiana»: che cosa te lo fa pensare? A me sembra il plurale maschile dell'aggettivo [“maiuscolo”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/maiuscolo/), sia in senso tipografico che in senso figurato: “caratteri maiuscoli”, “errori maiuscoli”, “per chi s’invecchia e langue Prepariam vetri [= bicchieri] maiuscoli” (Redi, citato in quella voce del Treccani).

Comment: Grazie per la segnalazione, @DaG. Sarà forse un regionalismo, non avendo mai usato o sentito tale parola che io ricordi. Maiuscolo mi suona molto come innumerabile e, al posto della sua versione plurale, userei "in maiuscolo".

Comment: Interessante; ma non hai mai neppure sentito “lettere maiuscole”, “tutto in maiuscole” e simili?

Comment: @black In effetti concordo col fatto che nemmeno io credo di averlo mai sentito, ma credo che sia perché capita raramente l'occasione di usarlo: quando si parla di "lettere" si usa il femminile, quando si parla di "uso" si usa il singolare

Comment: *Capitalizzare* non ha, che io sappia, significati connessi con lettere maiuscole. Quanto al primo esempio, non avrei alcuna obiezione a *dopo il punto fermo si pone uno spazio seguito dalla maiuscola* (sottintendendo “lettera”).

Answer (score 3):

Semplicemente, come ogni aggettivo, "maiuscolo" si declina concordemente al genere e al numero del sostantivo che lo regge:

> Una lettera *maiuscola*
>   Delle lettere *maiuscole*
>   Un errore *maiuscolo*
>   Degli errori *maiuscoli*

Credo che tu ti riferisca a questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/posts/5835/revisions); "lettera" è un sostantivo femminile quindi in questo caso quindi le hai azzeccate tutte e due (revisioni 3 e 5); nella revisione 3 ne hai corrette 2 (quindi corretto l'uso di "[lettere] maiuscole", plurale di "[lettera] maiuscola"), mentre nella revisione 5 ne hai corretta una (quindi corretto l'uso di "[lettera] maiuscola").

Se tu avessi citato come ragione dell'edit ad esempio "maiuscolo" *credo* che sarebbe stato comunque abbastanza chiaro, penso che tutti avrebbero capito che intendevi "[uso del] maiuscolo"; tuttavia "maiuscoli" sarebbe stato sbagliato, perché non avrebbe concordato né col genere di "lettera" né col numero di "uso".

Comment: “un'errore maiuscolo” è autoreferenziale? :-) Lascialo, ti prego.

Comment: Perdonami @DaG ma non sono sicuro di aver capito a cosa ti riferisci :)

Comment: Ho dei dubbi precisamente sull'uso come sostantivo: "scritto in maiuscole", "uso del maiuscolo" ("uso delle maiuscole/della maiuscola"??).

Comment: @Charo Sono tutti aggettivi sostantivati, quindi l'aggettivo sostantivato deve concordare col genere e col numero di ciò a cui ti vuoi riferire: [cont]

Comment: [cont] "scritto in maiuscole" -> ok, ma ti stai riferendo implicitamente alle "lettere maiuscole" intese come sostantivo; "uso del maiuscolo" -> ok, ma ti stai riferendo implicitamente al "fatto di essere maiuscoli" (spero di essere stato chiaro) inteso come sostantivo; "uso delle maiuscole" -> ok, ma ti stai riferendo implicitamente alle "lettere maiuscole" intese come sostantivo; "uso della maiuscola" -> ok, ma ti stai riferendo implicitamente all'uso della "lettera maiuscola" intesa come sostantivo

Comment: @Charo Non so se l'ho spiegato abbastanza bene, se hai dubbi ovviamente chiedi

Comment: E qual è il sostantivo che sarebbe sottinteso in "uso del maiuscolo"?

Comment: @Charo Non è facilissimo da spiegare, provo a dirlo in un altro modo e in un contesto: "*Il maiuscolo* è obbligatorio per gli acronimi" = "*Il fatto che le lettere siano maiuscole* è obbligatorio per gli acronimi"; quindi "il maiuscolo" = "il fatto che le lettere siano maiuscole", o "il fatto di essere maiuscoli"

Comment: Sicuro tu intendessi dire *un errore*, che non vuole l'apostrofo. E poi usare "maiuscoli" per qualificare qualcosa come grande è di una singolarità...maiuscola.

Comment: @black Ora capisco a cosa si riferiva DaG. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Paris_Tuileries_Garden_Facepalm_statue.jpg