# Come usare correttamente la maiuscola quando un estratto racchiuso tra doppie virgolette si trova all'inizio di un periodo?

Tags: capitalization

Parzialmente ispirato [da questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5851/1377).

Mi capita spesso di citare una frase od un breve estratto racchiudendolo tra doppie virgolette.

Dato che spesso la costruzione di un periodo è molto più chiara quando l'ordine è `soggetto -> verbo -> [...]`, se mi devo riferire alla frase o all'estratto in oggetto mi capita quindi di metterlo, nella costruzione del periodo, all'inizio della frase.

Questo mi pone un dubbio; partiamo dal fatto che indubbiamente se nella frase o nell'estratto a cui mi devo riferire la prima lettera è già maiuscola di suo il problema non si pone, per esempio:

> Il primo verso dell'Inferno di Dante è "Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita".
>   "Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita" è il primo verso dell'Inferno di Dante.

Ma quando la prima lettera della frase o dell'estratto *non* è già maiuscola di suo trovo giusto *non* scriverla con la maiuscola, altrimenti sarebbe (per quanto magari banale) comunque un'interpolazione che vorrei evitare fare.

> Il secondo verso dell'Inferno di Dante è "mi ritrovai per una selva oscura".
>   "mi ritrovai per una selva oscura" è il secondo verso dell'Inferno di Dante.

Trovo che sia giusto non scrivere con la maiuscola nemmeno la prima lettera della parola che segue la frase o l'estratto citato, perché difatto non è la prima lettera del periodo.

Questo però lascia il secondo caso, in cui l'ordine della costruzione è `soggetto -> verbo -> [...]` senza una maiuscola in assoluto.

Ho il dubbio su quanto sia corretto fare così.

Pertanto, è grammaticalmente corretto *non* usare la maiuscola né nella prima lettera di una frase o di un'estratto citato né nella prima lettera della parola che lo segue quando la frase o l'estratto citato sono racchiusi tra virgolette e posti all'inizio del periodo?

Comment: Questa non è una risposta vera e propria, ma personalmente comincerei comunque il periodo con la maiuscola, indipendente dalla posizione della citazione nel testo originario. Pensa a una singola parola: per te sarebbe un problema metterla maiuscola all'inizio della frase? «“Essere” è un verbo ausiliare», per esempio. Laddove fosse importante parlare proprio dell'uso di maiuscole e minuscole in un testo, si farà in modo di evitare l'ambiguità, magari centrando le citazioni.

Comment: @DaG No, se fosse più importante trasmettere il significato della citazione piuttosto che la citazione stessa letteralmente "immacolata" non avrei nessun problema, poi forse sono troppo pignolo io ma parte del dubbio è anche se mettere la maiuscola all'interno della citazione renda effettivamente la frase impeccabile grammaticalmente. Poi decisamente non è un grosso problema, è più curiosità. Forse alla fine mi ci sto anche arrovellando troppo. Se vuoi aggiungerla come risposta comunque hai il mio +1 intanto :)

Comment: Non è che per caso si può chiarire la domanda, che non ho capito niente.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Guarda la prima citazione; entrambi i casi sono corretti. Nella seconda citazione non sono sicuro se scrivere come nel secondo caso sia corretto, perché la maiuscola è completamente assente. Sarebbe giusto mettere la maiuscola all'interno delle virgolette / sull' "è"?

Comment: -1 addirittura? E' una domanda così banale / poco interessante?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Anzitutto, se si tratta di riportare una citazione, sarebbe piú consono l'uso delle virgolette francesi `« »`, o tuttalpiú delle virgolette a sergente `“ ”` piuttosto che utilizzare i semplici doppi apici `" "`, i quali sono maggiormente adatti a racchiudere parole di rilievo all'interno delle frasi.

Ciòdetto, sia per quanto riguarda la scelta delle virgolette sia per quanto in merito alle maiuscole/minuscole a inizio citazione all'avvio di una frase, non esiste una regola ferrea; gli stessi editori seguono un regolamento interno che potrebbe variare l'uno dall'altro. Vedasi, a titolo esemplificativo, le differenze editoriali optate dall'editore [Progressus](http://www.rivistaprogressus.it/wp-content/uploads/Norme-redazionali-Progressus.pdf) e dalla [Bottega Editoriale](http://www.bottegaeditoriale.it/questionidieditoria.asp?id=32).

È altresí vero che è prassi condivisa dai piú mantenere la maiuscola laddove la citazione originale la preveda, anche se tale citazione viene immessa all'interno di un nuovo costrutto.

> Il primo verso dell'*Inferno* di Dante è «Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita».
>
> Il secondo verso dell'*Inferno* di Dante è «mi ritrovai per una selva oscura».

Cosí come non è norma regolamentata ma, nuovamente, prassi condivisa dai piú, inserire la maiuscola alla citazione sebbene l'originale non la preveda quanto questa è inserita all'avvio di un nuovo costrutto.

> «Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita» è il primo verso dell'*Inferno* di Dante.
>
> «Mi ritrovai per una selva oscura» è il secondo verso dell'*Inferno* di Dante.

Piuttosto è importante adottare uno stile e mantenerlo per tutta la durata dello scritto.

Comment: Io, se proprio dovessi sentire la necessità di una maiuscola all'inizio di una frase che inizia con una citazione che non inizia con una maiuscola, scriverei: “«[M]i ritrovai per una selva oscura» è il secondo verso dell'Inferno di Dante.” Credo il senso delle parentesi quadrate sia chiaro, di talché non mi soffermo a spiegarlo.

Comment: «i semplici doppi apici " " ... sono maggiormente adatti a racchiudere parole di rilievo all'interno delle frasi» Non mi sono mai imbattuto in un uso simile: ne sei sicuro? In genere in tipografia gli apici semplici o doppi non si usano proprio in luogo delle virgolette (bensì per indicare secondi, pollici e altro, seppure).

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Certo, l'utilizzo delle parentesi quadre cui hai riportato come esemplificazione è chiaro, anche considerando la tematica affrontata. Però, personalmente, non mi è mai capitato di visionare tale utilizzo delle parentesi nelle citazioni a inizio frase. Né nei testi del secolo scorso sui quali ho lavorato, sebbene possano contarsi sulle dita di due mani, né tanto meno sui testi moderni. Dunque mi sorge spontanea una domanda: potresti citare qualche fonte d'utilizzo di questa forma da te citata?

Comment: @DaG Come sottolineavo in conclusione della mia risposta, in realtà non vi è una regolamentazione rigida sull'uso delle virgolette. Cosí come per quanto riguarda l'uso della maiuscola a inizio citazione. Per quanto io ne sappia, ogni editore sceglie una propria linea regolamentativa che si impegnerà a mantenere nelle proprie pubblicazioni. E sebbene i doppi apici si tendano a non usarli affatto, vi sono editori che hanno scelto di adottarli. E non è corretto etichettare tale scelta un errore. Tutto sommato si tratta di farne un uso il piú possibile corretto in mancanza di una regolamentazione.

Comment: @Wiccio: Grazie mille per le delucidazioni. Non ho mai detto che i doppi apici al posto delle virgolette siano un “errore”: è solo che non li ho mai visti in pubblicazioni professionali, ma non vuol dire niente.